# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always return false in Resolver

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to implement multitenancy in my ASP.NET Core project. I can capture the subdomain from the url and determine Tenant from there but somehow when I want to get the tenant from logged in user, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always return false, even tho the user is logged in. Here is the code:

```
public class CachingTenantResolver : MemoryCacheTenantResolver<Tenant>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    //private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    public CachingTenantResolver(
        ApplicationDbContext context, IMemoryCache cache, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
         : base(cache, loggerFactory)
    {
        _context = context;
        //_loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    // Resolver runs on cache misses
    protected override async Task<TenantContext<Tenant>> ResolveAsync(HttpContext context)
    {

        Tenant tenant = new Tenant { Name = "DefaultTenant", Domain = "www" };

        if(context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userId = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            Account account = _context.Accounts.Include("Tenant").FirstOrDefault(i => i.IdentityUserID == userId);
            tenant = account.Tenant;
        }
        else
        {
            var subdomain = context.Request.Host.Host.ToLower().Split('.');

            var tempTenant = await _context.Tenants
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Domain == subdomain[0]);

            if (tempTenant!=null)
            {
                tenant = tempTenant;
            }
        }
        return new TenantContext<Tenant>(tenant);
    }
//...the rest of the resolver
```

What did I miss? As far as I understand, the HttpContext should contain User information.

Comment: Can you provide the base class? Where do you get the http context from? Usually http context is only available in endpoints. When you want to access it outside of that scope, you have to register and inject IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: @alsami I believe it is from Saaskit.Multitenancy package. I haven't venture that far yet into their codes, but I wonder  how can I capture user login status outside of controller/razor. When I tried `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` here it always return false.

Comment: I found the problem. I should add `app.UseAuthentication` before calling the multitenancy injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call app.UseAuthentication() before multitenancy injection.

Comment: Injection in ConfigureServices method?